# Retrieve features from WFS using geotools

Tags: wfs, java, features, geotools

I am new to GI systems. I am trying to retrieve features from a WFS using geotools:

this is my snippet :

```
String url = "http://geodaten.metropoleruhr.de/poi/poi?request=GetFeature&service=wfs&version=1.1.0";
Map<String, Object> connectionParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL", url );

//connection
DataStore data = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(connectionParameters);
```

but I get `NullPointerException`.
Do I miss something ?

Comment: Strictly should be `service=WFS&`

Comment: If you use that URL and then add a request=GetCapabilities you'll have a URL like `http://geodaten.metropoleruhr.de/poi/poi?request=GetFeature&service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities` which fails because the first request parameter is honoured.  That is GeoTools is expecting a Capabilities response, but you are giving an incomplete GetFeature request and get  an error response

Answer (score 1):

GeoTools is expecting a base URL so you need something like:

```
String url = "http://geodaten.metropoleruhr.de/poi/poi?service=wfs&version=1.1.0";
```

or even just:

```
String url = "http://geodaten.metropoleruhr.de/poi/poi?";
```

Also from my quick test you will need to add

```
connectionParameters.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.WFS_STRATEGY.key, "mapserver");
```

to work around some issues the server has with the standard.